# Promise within another promise

Tags: javascript

I have a promise that gets for each `department` its `categories`, I have to add another level- for each `category` to get its `subcategories`.

I added another promise, I'm just wondering if this is the right way to do it, please advise.

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    const departments = await getDepartments();
    const departmentsWithcategories = await Promise.all(
      departments.map(async department => {
        const categories = await getCategories(department.id);
        categories.map(async category => {
          const subCategories = await getSubCategories(category.id);
          return { ...categories, subCategories };
        });
        return { ...department, categories };
      }),
    );
    this.setState({ departmentsWithcategories });
  };
```

Function before change:

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    const departments = await getDepartments();
    const departmentsWithcategories = await Promise.all(
      departments.map(async department => {
        const categories = await getCategories(department.id);
        return { ...department, categories };
      }),
    );
    this.setState({ departmentsWithcategories });
  };
```

Comment: Well, does it work? Does it give you any problems? It Right and wrong can be a bit subjective in cases where there isn't an actual fault

Comment: Well, I guess it's more of a UX concern. You are halting the render by executings several subqueries, where you could instead do a partial rendering of each `department`. Is there an added value of loading all that data upfront and awaiting chaining promises? What's the average rendering time? I cannot answer those questions as I do not have usage data, but I think that once you know the user behavior you'll get a clearer picture of what to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will also need another `Promise.all` to wait for the results of the inner loops. Also you were ignoring its return value, and probably you meant to spread the individual `category` not the `categories` array.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const departments = await getDepartments();
    const departmentsWithCategories = await Promise.all(departments.map(async department => {
        const categories = await getCategories(department.id);
        const categoriesWithSubcategories = Promise.all(categories.map(async category => {
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^
            const subCategories = await getSubCategories(category.id);
            return { ...catgory, subCategories };
//                      ^^^^^^^
        }));
        return { ...department, categories: categoriesWithSubcategories };
//                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }));
    this.setState({ departmentsWithCategories });
}
```